# Use Hero to switch between two child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

The [Hero library](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) makes it easy to add cool transitions to UINavigationControllers and such, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to switch between two child view controllers.

Ex:

```
self.isHeroEnabled = true
let c1 = MyController1()
let c2 = MyController2()

addChildViewController(c1)
addChildViewController(c2)

c2.view.isHidden = true

// Somewhere else in the app
func switchControllers(){
   // What to do?
}
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but don't you also need to the add in the views of `c1` and `c2` along side also adding them as children view controllers

Comment: I haven't used Hero Library, but usually child view controllers are added to a parent view controller. So your c1 and c2 would normally be on the same screen. So I don't understand switching between c1 and c2

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies, I was just writing some code off the top of my head. You do of course add the child views. That's not really the issue, I was just giving some code to clarify what I'm going for.